# Deleting an entry belonging to 2 entities Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, relational-database

I've been trying to solve a problem since morning and I can't figure it out.
I'm working on a project that uses Symfony 6 and PHP 8.0.

I have an OneToMany connection between Student and Grade -> Each Student can have many Grade objects. Each Grade relates to one Student.

But in the Grade entity, I also have a ManyToOne link between Grade and Course -> Each Grade relates to one Course. Each Course can have many Grade objects.

When I delete a student's grade (from the Student table), in the Grade table I encounter a behavior like this:
The studentID is deleted, but the courseID remains. I expected the entire entry from the Grade table to be deleted.

I tried to add `orphanRemove = true` on grade property from the Student table, and it's even worse. All grades for that course are deleted, including the course.
And I can understand why this happened. It's because I link the Grade both to the Student class and Course class, and I'm running into this problem:
*When using the orphanRemoval=true option Doctrine makes the assumption that the entities are privately owned and will NOT be reused by other entities. If you neglect this assumption your entities will get deleted by Doctrine even if you assigned the orphaned entity to another one*

I wonder how I could solve this problem. Is creating a cron job to delete all grades with **student_id = null** a good solution or is there a better alternative?

```
class Student extends AbstractUser
 {
    #[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'student', targetEntity: Grade::class, cascade: ['persist', 'remove'])]
    protected Collection $grades;
 }
```

```
class Grade {
    #[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: Student::class, inversedBy: 'grades')]
    protected ?Student $student;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: Course::class, cascade: ['persist', 'remove'], inversedBy: 'grades')]
    protected ?Course $course;
}
```

```
class Course {
    #[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'course', targetEntity: Grade::class, cascade: ['persist', 'remove'], orphanRemoval: true)]
    protected Collection $grades;
}
```

I also tried to add *nullable = false* like:

```
#[
   ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: Student::class, inversedBy: 'grades'),
   ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false, onDelete: 'CASCADE')
]
   protected ?Student $student;

#[
   ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: Course::class, inversedBy: 'grades'),
   ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false, onDelete: 'CASCADE')
]
   protected ?Course $course;
```

and I am struck by the logical error *An exception occurred while executing a query: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'student_id' cannot be null*

I would like to specify that I use EasyAdmin 4.0 to do this. In StudentCrudController my grades property looks like this:

```
CollectionField::new('grades')
   ->setEntryType(GradeType::class)
   ->setEntryIsComplex(),
```

Comment: Did you execute schema update or migration when you added `ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false, onDelete: 'CASCADE')` ?

Comment: Yes. I did it.  That's why I got an exception about integrity constraint violation, because I can't have student_id or course_id NULL anymore.

Comment: I noticed that entity `Course` has Many to One with itself, is it correct?

Comment: Good catch, Artem. Thank you! I copied the wrong code when I asked the question.
I have updated the answer with the correct property for Course entity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `cascade` parameter from `Grade::course`, because if you delete Grade, the Course and Grades belonging to it will be deleted

```
class Student extends AbstractUser
{
    #[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'student', targetEntity: Grade::class, cascade: ['persist', 'remove'])]
    protected Collection $grades;
}

class Grade {
   #[
      ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: Student::class, inversedBy: 'grades'),
      ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false, onDelete: 'CASCADE'),
   ]
   protected ?Student $student;

   #[
       ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: Course::class, inversedBy: 'grades'),
       ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false, onDelete: 'CASCADE'),
   ]
   protected ?Course $course;
}
```

Also you can add `orphanRemove = true` to `Student::grades`

Comment: I did it and I got the same error. *Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'student_id' cannot be null*

But I don't understand why I have this behavior here. This logic written by me works perfectly on the Course object.
If I delete a course, all grades for that course are automatically deleted.